# Python - How to parse and save JSON to MYSQL database

Tags: python, mysql, json

As the title indicates, how does one use python to elegantly access an API and parse and save the JSON contents onto a relational database (MYSQL) for later access?

Here, I saved the data onto a pandas object. But how do I create a mysql database, save the json contents onto it, and access the contents for later use?

```
# Libraries
import json, requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Set URL
url = 'https://api-v2.themuse.com/jobs'

# For loop to
for i in range(100):
    data = json.loads(requests.get(
        url=url,
        params={'page': i}
    ).text)['results']

data_norm = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: a tip: use `requests.get(<args>).json()['results']` instead of `json.loads(requests.get(<args>).text)['results']`

Comment: If it's a local project, you might want to consider a lightweight database `sqlite`, and python has built-in support https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Why are you even using `pandas` here? Also, you are overwriting `data` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I was using pandas first, but thought that it's better in the long run to build a database.

Comment: *why* are you using `pandas`? Whatever you are doing here doesn't make much sense. Is there any need for it? There are many ways to save a "json data" to a database. The approach you'd want to take depends on the nature of your data. Is it structured? Or do you just want to store it as blobs? This question seems too broad without more details.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How would you parse and save json data onto a mysql database?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your Mysql table on your server using something like [Mysql Workbench CE](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). then in python you do this. I wasnt sure if you want to use data in for loop or data_norm so for ease of use, here some functions. insertDb() can be put in your for loop, since data will be overwriten by itself in every iteration.

```
import MySQLdb

def dbconnect():
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='password',
            db='nameofdb'
        )
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Can't connect to database")
    return db

def insertDb():
    try:
        db = dbconnect()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO nameoftable(nameofcolumn) \
        VALUES (%s) """, (data))
        cursor.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is merely for storage for processing later, kind of like a cache, a varchar field is enough. If however you need to retrieve some structured jdata, JSON field is what you need.